# JQuery Slide Show Simplification

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5

I'm trying to come up with the most basic example of making a JQuery slide show where you click on the current image you're viewing and you cycle through a gallery of photos. I know its probably not the most basic example, because if I want to add a new image I have to code more JQuery. Is there a more abstract approach where I don't have to code JQuery in terms of div id's and let classes take care of the work?
Here is my JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#pic1").click(function() {
    $("#pic1").hide();
    $("#pic2").show();                
});  
$("#pic2").click(function() {
    $("#pic2").hide();
    $("#pic3").show();                
});
$("#pic3").click(function() {
    $("#pic3").hide();
    $("#pic1").show();                
});
});
```

The rest is here. 
http://jsfiddle.net/XjdTX/3/

Comment: You should include the main code in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

http://jsfiddle.net/XjdTX/11/

I changed the `<div id="slideframe">...</div>` to use a class instead. This will allow you to have multiple slide shows functioning off the same code, as shown in the jsFiddle. For toggling through the pics, the `pic` class is used and cycles based on the index of the clicked image.

There is also code in the jsFiddle that will fade the images instead of just toggling their visibility.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.slideframe').each(function() {

        var $pics = $(this).find('.pic'),
            max = $pics.length;

        $pics.on('click.slideframe', function(e) {
            var idx = $pics.index(this);
            if (idx < 0) {
                return false;
            }
            $(this).hide();
            $pics.eq(++idx % max).show();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You should use `$pics.on('click', handler)` instead of `$pics.click(handler)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // set display:none for all <img> tags except the first
    $('.pic:gt(0)').hide();

    // stores all matches for class="pic"
    var $slides = $('.pic');

    $slides.click(function(){
        // stores the currently-visible slide
        var $current = $(this);    
        if( $current.is($slides.last()) ) {
            $current.hide();
            $slides.first().show();
        } 
        // else, hide current slide and show the next one
        else {
            $current.hide().next().show(); 
        }
    });
});
```

**Edit** Changed to include element caching, as per ANeves's suggestion.

Full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/XRpeA/

Comment: You could suggest elements caching (e.g. `$(this)`).

Comment: @ANeves, I am about as far from being comfortable with JS as people come, so thanks for the suggestion. Did you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ta4YU/2/ ?

Comment: Precisely that!